# how to kill any process

Tags: command-line

- My process show using this command :

  ```
   abc@ABC:~$ ps -e | grep -e apt -e adept | grep -v grep
   2838 ?        00:00:11 aptd
  ```
- This `2838` Process kill using this command

  ```
   sudo kill -9 2838
  ```
- But also its give me Error

  ```
   bash: kill: (2838) - Operation not permitted
  ```

I am use `Ubuntu 12.04` now What can I do For this `Error`?

Comment: Use "killall aptd" and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use `sudo`.

```
sudo kill -9 2838
```

Then `pgrep -fl apt` to see if it is still running or

```
ps aux |grep aptd
```

to see who the user is and what the PID is:

```
phil     20438  0.0  0.0  11744   916 pts/2    S+   10:43   0:00 grep --colour=auto aptd
```

Comment: sorry I already use sudo ,I edit my question

Comment: Since aptd is a service try sudo service aptd stop

Comment: Come to think about it your system is trying to do an update if aptd is running. You don't want to kill that. You can turn off auto updates in the Ubuntu Software Center and Update Manager.

Comment: If may I restart then its resolve ?

Comment: Until it does is next update.  Be sure to turn off auto updates first.